# Lucene.NET MatchAllDocsQuery doesn't honor document boost?

Tags: sorting, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I have a Lucene index of document, all nearly identical (test 1, test 2, etc.) except that some have a higher boost than others. When using a default query (MatchAllDocsQuery OR .Parse("*:*") on the query parser) the documents come back in the order they went in every time. By adding a search term ("test" in this case), the document boost is apparent and the documents are sorted according to the boost. I can change the boost levels around and the new order is reflected in the results. All my code is pretty standard fair, I'm using a default Sort() is both cases.

I found that this same bug was [reported and fixed in Lucene back in 2005-2006](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-450?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), and I checked my MatchAllDocsQuery.cs file (Lucene .NET 2.9.2) and it seems to have this change present, but the behavior is as described in the ticket above.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Perhaps someone running the Java version has experienced this (or not)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, don't I feel silly now. This is as-designed behavior. I guess. According to *Lucene in Action*, MatchAllDocsQuery uses a constant for the boost.